# When using MVC what is best practice for deeply nested UI events?

Tags: model-view-controller

In MVC should deeply nested UI interaction events directly access a Controller or should the event bubble up to a View object? (Origin of question is from Flash based MVC)

For example a mouse click on a button

`Button-->ButtonsContainer-->OptionPanel-->Dashboard-->DashboardView-->Controller`

or

`Button-->Controller`

Comment: Depends on in what environment this is done. If you are talking frontend JS application, then I would slap a listener on `document.body` and manage it all via some front controller.

Answer (score 1):

I think, your Button-Click triggers a form commit which goes (normally as POST request) directly to an action in some controller - this depends on the routing config.
So there is no event-routing like WPF.